# How to make if condition in Nodejs Sequelize model query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use if condition in Nodejs Sequelize query using models.

I want to select users by `filter parameter` if there is filter parameter. If there isn't I want to select all users.
I did that in the following way, but I hardcoded this:

`var filterData = {  id: { $ne: null} };`

Is there a proper way to do that using Sequelize? Thanks.

```js
function getData(id, filter='') {
  var filterData = {  id: { $ne: null} };
  if (filter !== '') {
    filterData = {
      $or: [
        {firstName: {$like: '%' + filter + '%'}},
        {lastName: {$like: '%' + filter + '%'}}
      ]
    };
  }
  return models['Profile'].findAll({
    where: { profileId: id },
    include: [{
      model: models.Profile.scope('essentials'),
      where: filterData,
      as: 'entity'
    }]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've tried `var filterData = {}` or `var filterData = true` and that didn't work? If so, one other option would be to build your include object beforehand, and then add the where clause to it conditionally:

```
function getData(id, filter='') {
  var includeObj = {
    model: models.Profile.scope('essentials'),
    as: 'entity'
  }

  if (filter !== '') {
    includeObj.where = {
      $or: [
        {firstName: {$like: '%' + filter + '%'}},
        {lastName: {$like: '%' + filter + '%'}}
      ]
    };
  }

  return models['Profile'].findAll({
    where: { profileId: id },
    include: [includeObj]
  })
}
```

That avoids the awkward "where ID not equal to null" condition.

Also a small side note (and maybe you already know this and just prefer the more explicit code) but since empty string is falsey in javascript,

```
if (filter !== '') {
```

can be replaced with just

```
if (filter) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with empty object and empty string but I haven't thought about this way. About this ```if (filter !== '') ``` I have firts tried with this: `if (filter)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
where: {
          [Op.and]: [
            req.query.gigType && { gigType: req.query.gigType },
          ],
        },
```

You can just use it like this. This is not the answer to your question. But you can get an idea of how to write this. if there is req.query.gigType variable, giType = req.query.gigType filter applied. If not, the filter doesn't apply.

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! :)